# Hex long number to string that looks the same

Tags: c#

I've got a simple question i have got a long value presented in this way

```
long value = 0x001f0347
```

Now is there's a way to convert it to string that looks the same:

```
string value = "0x001f0347";
```

I have tried some converters but no luck.

Comment: Which converters have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *formatting* (`"x8"` format string - 8 hexadecimal digits):

```
  long value = 0x001f0347;

  string result = "0x" + value.ToString("x8");
```

If you prefer `Convert` then convert using `toBase == 16` and pad left up to `8` symbols

```
  string result = "0x" + Convert.ToString(value, 16).PadLeft(8, '0');
```